# How to select n top (or bottom) rows that given one variable sum more than x

Tags: r

In a data frame (copy data below) I would like to select (colum 2 named id iddentifies firms) the firms that account for 80% (or some other portion) of total of variable in column 3 during the whole period a (1998-2004) and during whole period b (2004-2010)

here the data:

```
structure(list(year = c(1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 
1998, 1998, 1998, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 
1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 
2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 
2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 
2001, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 
2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 
2002, 2002, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 
2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 
2003, 2003, 2003, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 
2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 
2004, 2004, 2004, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 
2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 
2005, 2005, 2005, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 
2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 
2006, 2006, 2006, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 
2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 
2007, 2007, 2007, 2007), id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 
21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 
8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 
25, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 
9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 1, 
2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 
21, 22, 23, 24, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 
17, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 26, 27, 28), variable = c(2708, 4747, 
2605, 3614, 3531, 1830, 1043, 1964, 1268, 2279, 2170, 4675, 2910, 
2243, 2320, 1111, 4261, 1093, 3940, 4611, 3024, 3736, 2119, 1688, 
2688, 1989, 1270, 1437, 2431, 1676, 4837, 1351, 2395, 3094, 4726, 
4228, 1621, 2914, 3435, 3922, 4432, 4900, 2286, 2203, 4711, 2254, 
1869, 1655, 3617, 2056, 3984, 1009, 4204, 4240, 2478, 3832, 2776, 
4309, 1459, 3753, 3126, 3103, 3571, 1220, 1537, 3817, 4759, 3518, 
1934, 1425, 4038, 3027, 2357, 4243, 3735, 4198, 1042, 3252, 3357, 
1253, 3105, 1208, 2420, 1824, 1329, 4831, 4741, 3356, 3157, 3176, 
1763, 1775, 1202, 2594, 4705, 4376, 1492, 2594, 3520, 2351, 1245, 
1712, 3218, 2564, 1189, 4889, 1480, 4314, 4684, 3312, 3404, 2925, 
1411, 2642, 3415, 2681, 2101, 2160, 1555, 1181, 2111, 4142, 1461, 
3427, 1506, 4501, 3281, 4734, 3053, 3504, 1619, 1171, 3739, 3160, 
3739, 4453, 1744, 4743, 3584, 1072, 1096, 3425, 4479, 4971, 4199, 
1118, 4258, 2969, 3908, 2920, 2163, 2252, 1606, 3588, 3689, 3929, 
4751, 2911, 3170, 3238, 2523, 2288, 2778, 4714, 1851, 3496, 3255, 
3705, 4168, 4403, 1775, 2435, 2228, 1444, 1040, 4989, 2655, 3232, 
2671, 1314, 1515, 4322, 3553, 4386, 4396, 4602, 3007, 1651, 1524, 
1360, 3756, 1490, 4356, 1671, 4163, 4344, 4290, 1737, 1870, 3753, 
3766, 4184, 3309, 3734, 4715, 1630, 2394, 1106, 2759)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -209L))
```

Answer (score 0):

With `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

top <- function(dt, p, min_year, max_year) {
  setorder(
    dt[
      year >= min_year & year <= max_year,
      .(total = sum(variable)),
      id
    ],
    -total
  )[
    1:min(sum(cumsum(total) < sum(total)*p) + 1, nrow(dt))
  ]
}

top(setDT(df), 0.8, 1998, 2004)
#>     id total
#>  1: 10 25233
#>  2:  2 23728
#>  3:  5 21090
#>  4: 17 20527
#>  5: 13 19811
#>  6:  7 19447
#>  7:  8 19410
#>  8: 14 18622
#>  9: 16 18577
#> 10:  1 18572
#> 11:  9 18524
#> 12: 12 17015
#> 13:  3 17004
#> 14: 20 16578
#> 15: 18 16085
#> 16: 24 15330
#> 17:  6 14699
#> 18: 11 14579
top(df, 0.8, 2004, 2010)
#>     id total
#>  1: 20 16487
#>  2: 17 14914
#>  3:  9 14445
#>  4: 24 14371
#>  5:  2 14260
#>  6: 13 14038
#>  7:  6 13688
#>  8: 23 12985
#>  9: 21 12969
#> 10: 16 12191
#> 11:  7 11873
#> 12: 14 11820
#> 13: 22 11480
#> 14:  1 11448
#> 15: 11 11363
#> 16:  8 10454
#> 17:  3 10439
```

Comment: Many thanks! Works perfectly.

I was also wondering if there is a way to solve it without creating a new function. In case someone else knows an alternative

Comment: You can always extract it from the function and hard-code the arguments. The function just saves some trouble if you'll be calling it multiple times.